# Center headings under an image within an article CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

I've got four articles laid out in grid, what I'm trying to achieve is to have an image in each article and then two headings centred below.

The articles and the images within are laid out as I want them by the h2 and h3s are on the left hand side of each article, rather than centred.

```css
.sportSection {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}

article {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

article img {
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: filter .4s ease-in-out;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

article img:hover {
  transition: filter .4s ease-in-out;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.articleHeading {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="sportSection">
  <article>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="takes/hotTakes/hotTake1/tsTestImage1.jpg"></a>
    <element class="articleHeading">
      <h2>Back of the net</h2>
      <h3>By Test Author</h3>
    </element>
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="takes/hotTakes/hotTake2/tsTestImage2.jpg"></a>
    <element class="articleHeadings">
      <h2>All on the line</h2>
      <h3>By Test Author</h3>
    </element>
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="takes/hotTakes/hotTake3/tsTestImage3.jpg"></a>
    <h2>Pace.Power.Pride</h2>
    <h3>By Test Author</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="takes/hotTakes/hotTake4/tsTestImage4.jpg"></a>
    <h2>Podium paradise</h2>
    <h3>By Test Author</h3>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: in `article` remove `width:25%` headings will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

The `article` you have is `width:25%`. Change it to `100%`.
Than you dont need the `.articleHeading` section in your CSS.